# MKPolylineView lineWidth need to be same everytime when zoom in or zoom out on MKMapview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, mapkit

I want `MKPolylineView` `lineWidth` needs to be same everytime when zoom in or zoom out on MKMap ?

I am drawing Route from A to B using `MKPolylineView` with all the specified points on the route.

I want to find corridor(polygon) around route as per specified distance in meters.suppose its 5 km (5000 meters). So corridor will be drawn on the mapview along with route.

I am attaching final image as output.

How to draw corridor(polygon) around the route ?

How to achieve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need a MKOverlayview that draws bluish 'corridor' according to a MKPolyline you give it and a distance you give it

```
@interface MyCooridor : MKOverlayView 
@property(retain) MKPolyline *polyline; 
@property(assign) double distance;
@end
```

to draw, implement `-(void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context`

---

add an overlay to the map in `mapview:viewForOverlay:` return the corridor view

Comment: thanks for your response.I know it could be draw using MKOverlayView. Can you please elaborate more on -(void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context ?